# Displaying Images from from Directory Outside of Webroot

Tags: php, linux, image

I am new to PHP, I have repository on my linux server, where web is hosted.

I have images folder 
Like /myfolder/image1-user etc. I want to display that on my web portal album. How can i do this?

**EDIT**
I have iterated the directory where pictures are stored. Now i have array list of path to the images, i used IMG SRC tag to show, but nothing is being shown, also i want URL of the each file in the repository that contains photos, 
i have link to image like this 
/myrepo/photos/photos-1/1.jpg and so on

Comment: What do you have so far and what exactly do you have a problem with? You probably want to start with http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the folder where your images are stored.

```
    <?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry<br/>";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I have array list to the path of all the files, now problem is to view them on portal. I used IMG src tag, but this is not showing the images, and also i want url of the photo in the repositry.

Answer (score 0):

symlink!

Say you want to display from your web root, e.g. /imgs/photos and your document root is the default '/var/www'

Then symlink that to the real folder below the webroot, for example:

`ln -s /real/path/to/my/photos /var/www/imgs/photos`
(on command line)

Then, when in your html you use src="/imgs/photos/great-photo.jpg" it will display "/real/path/to/my/photos/great-photo.jpg"

This may not work if you're on a shared hosting virtual server environment with all kinds of restrictions (such as open basedir etc.)